# Take an action if MapKit Map has zoomed into users location

Tags: ios, swift, mapkit

I am using this to zoom into the users location at startup.

```
func locationManager(manager:CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations:[AnyObject]) {
        var locationArray = locations as NSArray
        var locationObj = locationArray.lastObject as CLLocation
        var coord = locationObj.coordinate
        var newRegion = MKCoordinateRegion(center: coord, span: MKCoordinateSpanMake(spanX, spanY))
        mapView.setRegion(newRegion, animated: true)
    }
```

Now I'd like to take an action if the map has been zoomed into the users location. I've tried to use the mapDidChange delegate method, but this is fired a few times. Any thoughts how to do this the clever way? (iOS 8 / Swift)

Answer (score 0):

Just In my opinion , you can compare **newRegion's span** values with **map view's current span** values in regionDidChangeAnimated. If span values are the same, you can secondly play with "mapview.region". May be getting **visible mapView.region** and comparing it with **newRegion** or getting **centre coordinate of current visible region** and comparing it with **current location's coordinate** can work.